# How to Insert values into datatable from another datatable SQL

Tags: sql

I have **table1** with the following data :

| ID | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paul | 01-11-2020 |
| 1 | Paul | 03-11-2020 |

and have **table2** only with a **`Date`** column:

| Date |
| --- |
| 02-11-2020 |

I want to get output from those tables as:

| ID | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paul | 01-11-2020 |
| 1 | Paul | 02-11-2020 |
| 1 | Paul | 03-11-2020 |

Could someone help me how to join two tables to get the output like above. I tried so many ways but I couldn't solve this issue. Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CROSS JOIN` after applying `UNION ALL` in order to return from the both tables in a row-wise manner such as

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(tt.ID,t1.ID) AS ID,
                COALESCE(tt.Name,t1.Name) AS Name, tt.Date
  FROM table1 AS t1
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM table1  UNION ALL
             SELECT null,null,Date FROM table2) AS tt
 ORDER BY 3
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/XpkYwYdu)</kbd>

Comment: Barbaros Ozhan, Code is working perfect.Thank so much you....

Comment: If I want to add another column('Class') in 'Table1' How can I update the code

Comment: then you can use `SELECT null,null,Date,null FROM table2`, the rest is the same @bush

Comment: Ozhan, Could you help me on this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74704363/how-to-use-cross-join-twice-sql